# What's a good way to integrate voice command input in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on an application for a project, and a big goal of this app is to have voice commands. The plan is to eventually have this work with google assistant, siri and maybe even bixby if that's possible. But i'm new to flutter and I'm taking stuff step by step so first i want to allow voice commands in the app itself. I'm struggling to find a good package/widget for that. Any recommendations? Example codes would also help greatly

Comment: Here is a tutorial that implements what you are looking for down the road. https://fidev.io/ok-google-flutter/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the speech recognition  package - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/speech_recognition

Comment: Yes i did, i was checking if i could find something that's better if possible. I'm using it right now for the mean time